# JUnit 5 TestFactory Iterator

Tags: java, performance, kotlin, junit5

Lang: Kotlin
JDK: 1.8.0_162
JUnit 5: 5.2.0

Trying to get a large data set tested and have the following pseudo code as our framework.  Is there a supported way to go about streaming the test data in?  The test data is 4GB so returning this as an array isn't possible.

```
data class BigData(val id: Int, val bytes: ByteArray)

@TestFactory
fun TestIt() = getTestData()
    .map { (id, bytes) ->
        DynamicTest.dynamicTest("DataId: $id") {
            var valid = DoSomethingWithLargeData(bytes)
            Assertions.assertEquals(true, valid)
        }
    }

fun getTestData() = buildSequence {
    val inputStream = File(largeData).inputStream()

    inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
        lines.forEach {
            val parts = it.split(',')
            val id = parts[0].toInt()
            val bytes = decoder.decode(parts[1])
            yield(BigData(id, bytes))
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error with the above code

"Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot convert instance of kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence into a Stream: kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence@36a11785"

Answer (score 3):

Of course after I post the question, I figure it out.

```
@TestFactory
fun TestIt() : Iterator<DynamicTest> {
    return getTestData
    .map { (id, bytes) ->
        DynamicTest.dynamicTest("DataId: $id") {
            var valid = DoSomethingWithLargeData(bytes)
            Assertions.assertEquals(true, valid)
        }
    }.iterator()
}
```

The error kinda really does tell you what's wrong which lead me to trying to provide what it was asking for.

"TestIt() must return a Stream, Collection, Iterable, or Iterator of org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicNode"

Also, their documentation is good at showing examples of working dynamic tests

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: It might be worth adding an explanation to make it more useful for anyone else who has a similar/the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Here would be another example with lists when you want your test to run multiple test case at the same time.
I found the syntax a little bit different:

```kotlin
@TestFactory
fun multiplyDoubleTest() = listOf(
    listOf(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    listOf(0.0, 5.0, 0.0),
    listOf(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
    listOf(1.0, 6.0, 6.0),
    listOf(-2.0, 3.0, -6.0),
    listOf(2.0, 0.5, 1.0),
    listOf(2.0, 6.0, 12.0)
).map { (a, b, expectedResult) ->
    DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test:  $a x $b =  $expectedResult") {
        assertEquals(expectedResult, multiply(a, b))
    }
}
```

We have the multiply method doing `a * b` with each test case being (a, b, expectedResult) and then you do an `assertEquals` in the DynamicTest.

The name of the test can also be dynamic with `dynamicTest("Test:  $a x $b =  $expectedResult")`.
Also if you need to prepare the test case, you can use the `@TestFactory` this way

```kotlin
@TestFactory
fun multiplyWithInstructionBeforeTest(): List<DynamicTest> {
    val zero = 0.0
    return listOf(
        listOf(zero, 0.0, zero),
        listOf(zero, 1.0, zero)
    ).map { (a, b, expectedResult) ->
        DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test:  $a x $b =  $expectedResult") {
            assertEquals(expectedResult, multiply(a, b))
        }
    }
}
```

You can add some "Before Tasks" in the test Factory then return the `List<DynamicTest>` for it to be run with the other tests.